# How to use Oracle database for populating a list in a form

Tags: joomla-3.x, jdatabase

In using the MySQL Database, here is the default query in populating lists:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo(); 
$query = $db->getQuery(true); 
$query->select(array('name', 'email', 'username')) 
   ->from($db->quoteName('#__my_users')) 
   ->where($db->quoteName('user_id').'=42'); 
$db->setQuery($query); 
$row = $db->loadRow();
```

How can I configure which database I want to use? I need to get data from a different database which in my case, Oracle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a file called **configuration.php** in root directory. Open that file,
find:-

```
public $dbtype = 'mysqli';
```

change that value to:

```
 public $dbtype = 'oracle';
```

this will change database driver, list of drivers files can be found in:-

> libraries/joomla/database/driver folder,

For more info see this [article](https://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_database_using_JDatabase). Hope this helps.

**Update -** 
If you want to use only in some section then,
instead of getting instance of database like

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
```

try :-

```
$db = JDatabaseDriver::getInstance($options);
```

where

```
$options = array('driver' => 'driver_name', 'host' => 'host', 'user' => 'user', 'password' => 'password', 'database' => 'db_name', 'prefix' => 'prefix');
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. However I don't plan to use Oracle in my whole application, just within a form.

Comment: For that you can get instance of JDatabaseDriver, you can pass array of options here, with which driver you can use. For that please take a look at JDatabaseDriver class. [not tried though]

Comment: do you know what is the driver used in oracle? i tried using 'driver' => 'oracle' but results with an error:  Could not connect to PDO: could not find driver

Comment: I have just tried to get instance of database, where JDatabaseDriverOracle Object  is created. could you please show your tried code?

Comment: please take a look at my update

Answer (score 1):

Joomla Docs is a nice documentation site ;-)

**Connecting to an external database**
https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_connect_to_an_external_database

```
<?php
$option = array(); //prevent problems

$option['driver']   = 'mysql';            // Database driver name
$option['host']     = 'db.myhost.com';    // Database host name
$option['user']     = 'fredbloggs';       // User for database authentication
$option['password'] = 's9(39s£h[%dkFd';   // Password for database authentication
$option['database'] = 'bigdatabase';      // Database name
$option['prefix']   = 'abc_';             // Database prefix (may be empty)

$db = JDatabaseDriver::getInstance( $option );
?>
```